# IntelliJ terminal suddenly stopped showing path

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal

I am using IntelliJ community version 2019.3.1 on Win10

Terminal was working fine until suddenly it stopped showing the project path and only a cursor is blinking. Not able to type anything. Tried Clt+C but nothing working.

Comment: Does it help to restart IDE?

Comment: No help from restarting the IDE or system.

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?